# array_mutisort function is not working

Tags: php, arrays

I have this code:

```
array_multisort($year, SORT_ASC, $wpjobus_resume_work);

// Print sorted array.
echo '<pre>';
print_r($wpjobus_resume_work);
```

I have in year var the values:

1990
1995
2013

but the array always show in this order:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => GE 
            [1] => CEO
            [2] => 1995
            [3] => 2013
            [4] => Full Time
            [5] => Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque posuere est est, nec hendrerit quam vehicula id. Quisque sed nisl sit amet ipsum euismod pharetra. Nullam vel arcu eget ex pharetra imperdiet ac vitae nibh. Nullam vitae dolor pretium nibh semper ornare ac in sem. Quisque in malesuada dui. Suspendisse dapibus semper accumsan. Donec ut eleifend eros. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Maecenas ut felis neque.
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => SAP
            [1] => VP
            [2] => 1990
            [3] => 1995
            [4] => Freelance
            [5] => Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque posuere est est, nec hendrerit quam vehicula id. Quisque sed nisl sit amet ipsum euismod pharetra. Nullam vel arcu eget ex pharetra imperdiet ac vitae nibh. Nullam vitae dolor pretium nibh semper ornare ac in sem. Quisque in malesuada dui. Suspendisse dapibus semper accumsan. Donec ut eleifend eros. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Maecenas ut felis neque.
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Google
            [1] => Director
            [2] => 2013
            [3] => 2014
            [4] => Freelance
            [5] => Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque posuere est est, nec hendrerit quam vehicula id. Quisque sed nisl sit amet ipsum euismod pharetra. Nullam vel arcu eget ex pharetra imperdiet ac vitae nibh. Nullam vitae dolor pretium nibh semper ornare ac in sem. Quisque in malesuada dui. Suspendisse dapibus semper accumsan. Donec ut eleifend eros. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Maecenas ut felis neque.
        )

)
```

so I think the array sort function is not working properly. What to do? any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `array_multisort` expects there to be a correspondence between the two arrays. When it moves an element of `$year` to a new position, it moves the corresponding element of `wpjobus_resume_work` to the same position. Since `$year` is already sorted, nothing needs to be moved.

Comment: If you want to sort by a specific field in `$wpjobus_resume_work`, use `usort`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [**usort()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) instead. Example:

```
function custom_sort($a, $b)
{
    if ($a[2] == $b[2]) return 0;
    return ($a[2] < $b[2]) ? -1 : 1;
}

usort($your_arr, "custom_sort");

print '<pre>';
print_r($your_arr);
print '</pre>';
```